# C++ Builder - Moving a chess piece on board moves the next piece

Tags: c++, c++builder, chess

I've got a problem. I have a chess game and I wanted to make my pieces move random on board. I don't know why, but when I move a piece, the next piece moves, so I wrote move(piece-1). In that case, only the first piece can't move. How to solve this?

formaJoc.cpp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "formaJoc.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
#define MAX_FIGURI 20
TfJoc *fJoc;
Test fnc;
Piece *pc[MAX_FIGURI];
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TfJoc::TfJoc(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{

        blBoard[0] = new Board (0, 0, fJoc);

        BlackRook1[0]   =  new bkRook1  ( 40, 40, fJoc);
        BlackRook1[0]   -> LoadImg();
        BlackRook2[0]   =  new bkRook2  (292, 40, fJoc);
        BlackRook2[0]   -> LoadImg();
        BlackKnight1[0] =  new bkKnight1( 76, 40, fJoc);
        BlackKnight1[0] -> LoadImg();
        BlackKnight2[0] =  new bkKnight2(256, 40, fJoc);
        BlackKnight2[0] -> LoadImg();
        BlackBishop1[0] =  new bkBishop1(112, 40, fJoc);
        BlackBishop1[0] -> LoadImg();
        BlackBishop2[0] =  new bkBishop2(220, 40, fJoc);
        BlackBishop2[0] -> LoadImg();
        BlackQueen[0]   =  new bkQueen (148, 40, fJoc);
        BlackQueen[0]   -> LoadImg();
        BlackKing [0]   =  new bkKing  (184, 40, fJoc);
        BlackKing [0]   -> LoadImg();
        BlackPawns[0]   =  new bkPawn  ( 40, 76, fJoc);
        BlackPawns[0]   -> LoadImg();
        BlackPawns[1]   =  new bkPawn  ( 76, 76, fJoc);
        BlackPawns[1]   -> LoadImg();
        BlackPawns[2]   =  new bkPawn  (112, 76, fJoc);
        BlackPawns[2]   -> LoadImg();
        BlackPawns[3]   =  new bkPawn  (148, 76, fJoc);
        BlackPawns[3]   -> LoadImg();
        BlackPawns[4]   =  new bkPawn  (184, 76, fJoc);
        BlackPawns[4]   -> LoadImg();
        BlackPawns[5]   =  new bkPawn  (220, 76, fJoc);
        BlackPawns[5]   -> LoadImg();
        BlackPawns[6]   =  new bkPawn  (256, 76, fJoc);
        BlackPawns[6]   -> LoadImg();
        BlackPawns[7]   =  new bkPawn  (292, 76, fJoc);
        BlackPawns[7]   -> LoadImg();

        WhiteRooks[0]   =  new whRook  ( 40, 292, fJoc);
        WhiteRooks[0]   -> LoadImg();
        WhiteRooks[1]   =  new whRook  (292, 292, fJoc);
        WhiteRooks[1]   -> LoadImg();
        WhiteKnights[0] =  new whKnight( 76, 292, fJoc);
        WhiteKnights[0] -> LoadImg();
        WhiteKnights[1] =  new whKnight(256, 292, fJoc);
        WhiteKnights[1] -> LoadImg();
        WhiteBishops[0] =  new whBishop(112, 292, fJoc);
        WhiteBishops[0] -> LoadImg();
        WhiteBishops[1] =  new whBishop(220, 292, fJoc);
        WhiteBishops[1] -> LoadImg();
        WhiteQueen[0]   =  new whQueen (148, 292, fJoc);
        WhiteQueen[0]   -> LoadImg();
        WhiteKing [0]   =  new whKing  (184, 292, fJoc);
        WhiteKing [0]   -> LoadImg();
        WhitePawns[0]   =  new whPawn  ( 40, 256, fJoc);
        WhitePawns[0]   -> LoadImg();
        WhitePawns[1]   =  new whPawn  ( 76, 256, fJoc);
        WhitePawns[1]   -> LoadImg();
        WhitePawns[2]   =  new whPawn  (112, 256, fJoc);
        WhitePawns[2]   -> LoadImg();
        WhitePawns[3]   =  new whPawn  (148, 256, fJoc);
        WhitePawns[3]   -> LoadImg();
        WhitePawns[4]   =  new whPawn  (184, 256, fJoc);
        WhitePawns[4]   -> LoadImg();
        WhitePawns[5]   =  new whPawn  (220, 256, fJoc);
        WhitePawns[5]   -> LoadImg();
        WhitePawns[6]   =  new whPawn  (256, 256, fJoc);
        WhitePawns[6]   -> LoadImg();
        WhitePawns[7]   =  new whPawn  (292, 256, fJoc);
        WhitePawns[7]   -> LoadImg();

}

int id, row, col;
int &porecla=id;
int rowColToPixel[10] = {40, 76, 112, 148, 184, 220, 256, 292, 0, 331};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void movePiece(int piece, int col, int row)
{
   int left = rowColToPixel[col];
   int top  = rowColToPixel[row];
      switch (piece)
      {
      case(1): {fJoc->BlackRook1[1]->imPiece->Left=left;fJoc->BlackRook1[1]->imPiece->Top=top;break;}
      case(2): {fJoc->BlackKnight1[1]->imPiece->Left=left;fJoc->BlackKnight1[1]->imPiece->Top=top;break;}
      case(3): {fJoc->BlackBishop1[1]->imPiece->Left=left;fJoc->BlackBishop1[1]->imPiece->Top=top;break;}
      case(4): {fJoc->BlackQueen[1]->imPiece->Left=left;fJoc->BlackQueen[1]->imPiece->Top=top;break;}
      case(5): {fJoc->BlackKing[1]->imPiece->Left=left;fJoc->BlackKing[1]->imPiece->Top=top;break;}
      case(6): {fJoc->BlackBishop2[1]->imPiece->Left=left;fJoc->BlackBishop2[1]->imPiece->Top=top;break;}
      case(7): {fJoc->BlackKnight2[1]->imPiece->Left=left;fJoc->BlackKnight2[1]->imPiece->Top=top;break;}
      case(8): {fJoc->BlackRook2[1]->imPiece->Left=left;fJoc->BlackRook2[1]->imPiece->Top=top;break;}
      case(9): {fJoc->BlackPawns[8]->imPiece->Left=left;fJoc->BlackPawns[8]->imPiece->Top=top;break;}
      }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TfJoc::btnStartClick(TObject *Sender)
{
        exit(0);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TfJoc::btnExitClick(TObject *Sender)
{
        exit(0);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TfJoc::Image1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
        void LoadImg();        
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TfJoc::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
        fnc.Test123("Muie!");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TfJoc::bkRook1MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 1;}
void __fastcall TfJoc::bkKnight1MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 2;}
void __fastcall TfJoc::bkBishop1MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 3;}
void __fastcall TfJoc::bkQueenMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 4;}
void __fastcall TfJoc::bkKingMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 5;}
void __fastcall TfJoc::bkBishop2MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 6;}
void __fastcall TfJoc::bkKnight2MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 7;}
void __fastcall TfJoc::bkRook2MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 8;}
void __fastcall TfJoc::bkPawnMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 9;}

void __fastcall TfJoc::whRookMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 10;}
void __fastcall TfJoc::whKnightMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 11;}
void __fastcall TfJoc::whBishopMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 12;}
void __fastcall TfJoc::whQueenMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 13;}
void __fastcall TfJoc::whKingMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 14;}
void __fastcall TfJoc::whPawnMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) {id = 15;}

void __fastcall TfJoc::imBoardMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
        if (id != 99) {
                col = (X - 40) / 36;
                row = (Y - 40) / 36;
                movePiece(::id-1, col, row);
                id=99;
                //ShowMessage(id);
        }
}
```

formaJoc.h

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef formaJocH
#define formaJocH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Classes.hpp>
#include <Controls.hpp>
#include <StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Forms.hpp>
#include <ExtCtrls.hpp>
#include <Graphics.hpp>
#include <jpeg.hpp>
#include <Dialogs.hpp>
#include <windows.h>
#include "whBishop.h"
#include "bkBishop.h"
#include "whRook.h"
#include "bkRook.h"
#include "whKnight.h"
#include "bkKnight.h"
#include "whKing.h"
#include "bkKing.h"
#include "whQueen.h"
#include "bkQueen.h"
#include "whPawn.h"
#include "bkPawn.h"
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "Board.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TfJoc : public TForm
{
        friend class Piece;
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
        TButton *btnStart;
        TButton *btnExit;
        TButton *Button1;
        TImage *Image1;
        void __fastcall btnStartClick(TObject *Sender);
        void __fastcall btnExitClick(TObject *Sender);
        void __fastcall Image1Click(TObject *Sender);
        void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
private:
public:

        Board* blBoard[1];

        bkRook1*   BlackRook1[1];
        bkKnight1* BlackKnight1[1];
        bkBishop1* BlackBishop1[1];
        bkQueen*   BlackQueen[1];
        bkKing*    BlackKing[1];
        bkBishop2* BlackBishop2[1];
        bkKnight2* BlackKnight2[1];
        bkRook2*   BlackRook2[1];
        bkPawn*    BlackPawns[8];

        whRook*   WhiteRooks[2];
        whKnight* WhiteKnights[2];
        whBishop* WhiteBishops[2];
        whQueen*  WhiteQueen[1];
        whKing*   WhiteKing[1];
        whPawn*   WhitePawns[8];

        void __fastcall TfJoc::bkRook1MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
        void __fastcall TfJoc::bkKnight1MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
        void __fastcall TfJoc::bkBishop1MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
        void __fastcall TfJoc::bkQueenMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
        void __fastcall TfJoc::bkKingMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
        void __fastcall TfJoc::bkBishop2MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
        void __fastcall TfJoc::bkKnight2MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
        void __fastcall TfJoc::bkRook2MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
        void __fastcall TfJoc::bkPawnMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);

        void __fastcall TfJoc::whRookMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
        void __fastcall TfJoc::whKnightMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
        void __fastcall TfJoc::whBishopMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
        void __fastcall TfJoc::whQueenMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
        void __fastcall TfJoc::whKingMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
        void __fastcall TfJoc::whPawnMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);

        void __fastcall imBoardMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
      TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);

        __fastcall TfJoc(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TfJoc *fJoc;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Like this is every class:

```
bkBishop1::bkBishop1(unsigned int a, unsigned int b, TfJoc* fJoc):Piece(a, b, fJoc)
{
        nBishop1 = "Imagini/Nebun1.bmp";
        imPiece -> Left = a;
        imPiece -> Top = b;
        imPiece -> OnMouseDown = fJoc -> bkBishop1MouseDown;
}

void bkBishop1::LoadImg()
{
        imPiece->Picture->LoadFromFile(nBishop1);
}

bkBishop2::bkBishop2(unsigned int a, unsigned int b, TfJoc* fJoc):Piece(a, b, fJoc)
{
        nBishop2 = "Imagini/Nebun1.bmp";
        imPiece -> Left = a;
        imPiece -> Top = b;
        imPiece -> OnMouseDown = fJoc -> bkBishop2MouseDown;
}

void bkBishop2::LoadImg()
{
        imPiece->Picture->LoadFromFile(nBishop2);
}
```

Comment: You might want to go to some forum and talk about your code. There is a lot of space for improvement. If you have a big block of code with lines that look very similar, in most cases there is a better way to do it. May I ask why every different piece has it's own class instead of there being a general class for all pieces? And why you use pixel coordinates when you could go with grid coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You move `fJoc->BlackRook1[1]`, but that value is outside the valid range for the array `BlackRook1`.

The line

```
bkRook1*   BlackRook1[1];
```

only defines one single element, which is `BlackRook1[0]`.

The reason "the next piece moves" is pure chance. It is *undefined behavior* to address an array object beyond its bounds, and actually anything may happen – including "appears to work correctly", or, as in your case, "appears to work, apart from this minor thing".

I imagine it happens to work in your case because all of the object initializations are one after another, so "beyond" happily points to the next one created. (All apart from the last one, that is. Feel free to experiment.)

Comment: So how should I make them move correctly?

Comment: I solved it. Thanks! I changed BlackRook1[1] to BlackRook1[0].